# htonl() vs __builtin_bswap32()

Tags: c, linux, gcc, endianness

`__builtin_bswap32()` is used to reverse bytes (it's used for littel/big endian issues (from gcc)).

`htonl()` is used to reverse bytes too (conversion from host to network).

I checked both functions and they returns the same result.

Are there some one who can confirm that both functions do the same thing? (standard refences are appreciated)

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider the accepted answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just look at source code : (example from glib 2.18)

```
#undef htonl
#undef ntohl

uint32_t
htonl (x)
uint32_t x;
{
    #if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
       return x;
    #elif BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
       return __bswap_32 (x);
    #else
       # error "What kind of system is this?"
    #endif
}
weak_alias (htonl, ntohl)
```

And : `#define __bswap_32(x) ((unsigned int)__builtin_bswap32(x))`

Source here : http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.18/htonl_8c_source.html

As you can see, `htonl` only call `__builtin_bswap32` on little-endian machines.

Answer (score 36):

I disagree with your statement that `htonl()` is used to reverse byte order. It is used to convert from host to network byte order. Depending on the byte order of the host, that may, or may not, result in byte order being reversed.

I suggest that you use the function that expresses the correct semantic intent:

- If you wish to convert from host to network byte order, use `htonl()`.
- If you wish to reverse byte order, use `__builtin_bswap32()`.

Comment: So they are the same if the architecture is little endian

Comment: @MOHAMED Correct. But on a big endian machine, the compiler will turn `hotonl()` into a simple `return input`.

Answer (score 6):

bswap_32 always reverse byte order, on any architecture.

htonl/ntohl reverses byteorder on little endian machines only.

For example, on PowerPC (big endian), ntohl/htonl just returns input value, 
no more, while bswap32 anyway will reverse byte order.

Comment: So they are the same if the architecture is little endian